# C# application on IIS returns no response - timed out?

Tags: c#, iis, timeout

We have a C# web application on IIS 8.5.
When we submit GET request to the application URL, we get the following results.

1. If the processing time of the request is short (less than 2-3 min), we get HTTP response from IIS and it works fine.
2. If the processing time is long (more than a hour or so), we cannot get HTTP response to a client even though the application ends on server side.

We think that a timeout might occur but we don't have any idea what timeout setting effects on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way do you send the request? Do you have some code for that? The default value for an `HttpWebRequest` is [100 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx).

Comment: We send the request from Excel VBA.

Comment: Set objHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Comment: Our code in the VBA is like this:
--
Set objHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttpRequest.SetTimeouts 9999999, 9999999, 9999999, 9999999
objHttpRequest.Open "GET", strURL, False, "foo", "bar"
objHttpRequest.Send
objHttpRequest.WaitForResponse